# Font awesome working in local but not on site

Tags: fonts, upload, font-awesome, webfonts

I'm testing a website with font-awesome on localhost and it works fine; but when I upload it to my remote site it doesn't show the fonts anymore. How can I fix it? Tried all debugging but not worked.

The site is there www.sevotec.it/ordinefcs

Comment: Not relevant to the font thing.

Comment: Do you see the icons in header? Or in the circles, where there are "info farmaco 1, 2, 3..."? In there, I expect to see some icons of Font-Awesome.

Comment: Sadly, I can't manage my server settings. Can you give me the link you used? It would be great. :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me, but this doesn't explain why, with the same settings, on my computer it works and on remote it doesn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a problem with the MIME types being reported by your server for the fonts. You need to ensure that Apache / IIS / whatever reports the correct filetype for the font files to be used in your browser. [FontAwesome list what the server MIME type headers should be here](https://github.com/EnlightenAgency/Server-Setup-MIME-Types-Headers/blob/master/font-mimetypes.txt).

However, as you say you can not alter the configuration, I suggest using a CDN for displaying the icons.

For example, the [Getting Started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) page suggests using Bootstrap CDN. Change the reference in your `<head>` element to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

And the icons will show up.

Comment: Weird one. This fixed it for me.